# Is there a public-accessible scale in Naha International Airport in Okinawa?

Tags: luggage, airports, okinawa, oka, naha

I don't travel light. My backpack is usually about 17kg but when boarding my last flight the check-in scale thought it was 19kg. Sadly my next flight, the day after tomorrow, has a 15kg luggage limit.

I can transfer some small heavy items to my carry-on and I do have some things I can throw away but my current accommodation doesn't have a way to weigh my stuff. I don't want to get rid of more than necessary.

If I arrive a good few hours early can I weight my stuff at Naha airport while I re-pack? I've done this at a couple of airports in the past but can't remember seeing scales available in every airport I've been to.

Comment: I have been lucky when asking at a quiet check in counter, to use their scales. That was in Europe, where I spoke the local language.

Comment: There are some very small electronic scales designed specifically for weighing luggage, are small enough to pack in your bag, and cheap enough that if you lose it you won't cry over it.Allows you to rearrange your luggage in the comfort & convenience of your sleeping accommodations instead of spreading your luggage across a counter at the airport. Wife & I toted one around Europe a few summers ago.

Comment: Or just walk up to a closed checkin counter and use its scale.

Comment: @AlexanderChristiansson I think I would feel rude doing that (-: But I might try it next time I need it.

Comment: @FreeMan Normally for years and years I've only book flights where the luggage limit is 20kg, but this time I had to unexpectedly book a flight with no notice. It is a good idea though and I'll keep an eye out for one.

Comment: There's nobody in line at a closed check in counter, there (usually) isn't any staff there, either, so there shouldn't be any reason to feel "rude" about using the scale. Unless, of course, 7 other people have the same idea and you cut in front of them.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The answer is **YES**!

I decided I had no better plans in Naha than to walk and explore, so why not walk and explore to the airport?

International departures has one or two electronic scales near the Peach check-in counters that are designed for carry-on luggage but might work for larger luggage too.

[image: Carry-on scale at international Peach check-in]

Then there's a couple more near the ANA check-in counters that are definitely suitable for both checked luggage and carry-on.

[image: Checked & carry-on scale at international ANA check-in]

Over at the busier domestic departures there are more scales just like the ones at ANA International, some of which are right next to desks labelled "repacking area".

[image: Checked and carry-on scale at domestic check-in]

Comment: Well equipped airport in this respect. Thanks for sharing your information.

Comment: Yes I've been both lucky and unlucky at other airports before, but hadn't noticed such a well thought-out and implemented scale setup as this anywhere I can recall.

Comment: 7 kg or 10 kg allowance?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Wouldn’t be surprised if it differed per airline

Comment: Yes Peach, a Japanese discount airline has 7kg limit for carry-on while ANA, a Japanese full-price airline has a 10kg limit for carry-on. That's my understanding at least.